# How do I identify the shape of a Face in ios sdk.(face like diamond,heart,oval,rectangular)

Tags: iphone, ios, opencv, image-processing, ios4

I am new in `IOS Development`.

How I recognize the shape of Face in `ios sdk`.(face like diamond,heart,oval,rectangular).

Is any API available for `face recognition`.Is this possible with `opencv` ?

Please give any solutions.